# Potential causes of 'permission_name is not a member of the user'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

My app requests permissions required to do a specific task when needed, so the permissions vary. It does ask for permissions and all seems to go down smoothly there. However when I go to request something like 'user_education_history' I am greeted with a response like 'user_education_history is not a member of the user.' If I change `user_education_history` to something else like 'user_likes' same error with this request occurs.

Anybody had issue like this before?
Cheers.

PS: Code that asks for permissions, `checkPerms()` just checks whether permissions are ok and changes the button label from Login to Logout and vise-versa:

```js
function authPerms() {
    if($('#fb_button').html()==='Log In') {
        FB.login(function (response) {
            checkPerms();
        }, {scope: $('#<%=pList.ClientID %>').val() }); //The permissions are read from hidden field (this can vary).
    }
    else {
        FB.logout();
        checkPerms();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you request the permissions?

Comment: I have a suspicion my FQL query is incorrect: SELECT user_birthday, friends_birthday FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I was using permission names as the names of items to request. Unfortunately, permission names are not the same as the names of members.